# Attribute "deprecated" to namespace in C++17

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17

I have created C++ program to experiment of `deprecated` keyword of C++17.

It's working fine in **clang(3.8.0)**, But, **g++(5.4.0)** gives an error.

```
source_file.cpp:9:11: error: expected identifier before ‘[’ token
 namespace [[ deprecated ]] bar
           ^
source_file.cpp:9:28: error: ‘bar’ does not name a type
 namespace [[ deprecated ]] bar
                            ^
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:16:5: error: ‘bar’ has not been declared
     bar::var = 10;
```

**Why?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace foo  
{ 
  int var; 
}

namespace [[ deprecated ]] bar
{ 
  int var; 
}

int main() 
{
    bar::var = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Are you sure 5.4 supports it already?

Comment: According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) it is supported since gcc 4.9. And it is allowed on namespaces, from [dcl.attr.deprecated]: "The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, a namespace, an enumeration, an enumerator, or a template specialization."

Comment: You  need to get up to g++ 6.1, and as of 8.0 it still be warning.

Comment: Even at [g++ head](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2bsduoDPVvQ3pGyf) the attribute is straight up ignored. I'd say you have found a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error message: "expected *identifier* before `[` token". 
The *identifier* is `bar`, and it has to appear **before** `[`. So:

```
namespace bar [[deprecated]]
{ }
```

Tested with GCC6.3